# Mailgun Email sender isn't what its supposed to be

Tags: django, mailgun, django-email

So ive just set up django emails with mailgun, and sent the first email. This is the config I have in Django:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST', default='')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', default=587, cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'postmaster@mg.smartsurvey.xyz'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', default='')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', default=True, cast=bool)

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'SmartSurvey <noreply@smartsurvey.xyz>'
```

This is the view that sends the email:

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
subject = 'Activate your SmartSurvey account'
message = render_to_string('email/email_activation.html', {
    'name': user.get_full_name(),
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    })
user.email_user(subject, message)
```

And I want the sender to be `SmartSurvey <noreply@smartsurvey.xyz>`, however it currently sends like: `noreply=smartsurvey.xyz@mg.smartsurvey.xyz on behalf of SmartSurvey <noreply@smartsurvey.xyz>`

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs whenever the domain you input in your From: field does not match the domain you are using with Mailgun. Make sure these align to prevent "on behalf of" notation.

Comment: So the `EMAIL_HOST_USER` has to align with the domain from mailgun? what do you mean by domain? smartsurvey.xyz??

Comment: Yeah, the domain you added and are using with Mailgun. This looks to be mg.smartsurvey.xyz based on your EMAIL_HOST_USER. So in this case you will want the domain in your From: address to be the same, so you would have to change DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL to 'SmartSurvey <noreply@mg.smartsurvey.xyz>'